# Problemas com paginação no SLIM com Pager

Tags: php, mvc, paginação, slim

Como fazer a mudança de página usando o Pear-Pager no SLIM Framework?

O código da `router` é:

```
    $app->get('/imoveis(/:pg)', function($pg = '') use($app) {
    $imoveis = array('casa 1', 'casa 2', 'casa 3', 'casa 4', 'casa 5', 'casa 6', 'casa 7', 'casa 8', 'casa 9', 'casa 10');
    $params = array(
        'mode' => 'Jumping',
        'perPage' => 3,
        'delta' => 4,
        'itemData' => $imoveis,
        'append' => false,
        'path' => site_url().'imoveis/' ,
        'fileName' => '%d',
        'altNext' => 'Próximo',
        'nextImg' => '>>Próximo',        
    );
    $pager = Pager::factory($params);
    $data = $pager->getPageData();
    $links = $pager->getLinks();

    $dados = array(
        'titulo' => 'Nossos imóveis',
        'pagina' => 'imoveis',
        'menu_hover' => 3,
        'dados' => $data,
        'links' => $links,
    );

    $app->render('layout.php', $dados);
});
```

e o da `view` é:

```php
<?php 
foreach ($dados as $item):
    echo $item->codigo.'<br />';
endforeach;
echo $links['all'];
?>
```

Quando eu clico no número da página ele simplesmente muda na URL mas o resultado continua o mesmo.

Comment: Veja se isso pode ajudar tmb -> http://draft.studiokoalla.com/2015/03/paginacao-com-slim-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente definir o "currentPage" no `params`:

```
'currentPage' => $pg,
```

Ele deve está dando conflito com a forma que o slim pega os dados.

Na dúvida veja a [lista completa dos parâmetros que voce pode definir](http://pear.php.net/manual/pt_BR/package.html.pager.factory.php).